# List of lists to dict with every item in sublist as key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to transform following `list` into a `dict` with every item of the sublist as key, the values should be the rest of the elements within the sublist.

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6]]
```

Finished product should look like this:

```
dict_of_list = { '1': [(2,3)],
                 '2': [(1,3)],
                 '3': [(1,2)],
                 '4': [(5,6)],
                 '5': [(4,6)],
                 '6': [(4,5)]}
```

Comment: Yes. You would like to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of filtering the items, you should use subscripts around their positions.  This will avoid any issues with duplicate items and be more efficient:

```
L = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]

D = { v:sl[:i]+sl[i+1:] for sl in L for i,v in enumerate(sl) }


# {1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2], 4: [5, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some nested comprehension should work:

```
{k: [*filter(k.__ne__, l)] for l in list1 for k in l}
# {1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2], 4: [5, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [4, 5]}
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates in the sublists as we are just testing the other elements for inequality (`k.__ne__`). Otherwise:

```
{
    k: [x for i, x in enumerate(l) if i != j] 
    for l in list1 for j, k in enumerate(l)
}
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]

answer = {}
for subl in L:
    for i,k in enumerate(subl):
        answer[k] = [tuple(e for ii,e in enumerate(subl) if i!=ii)]
```

Output:

```
In [138]: for k,v in answer.items(): print(k,v)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
1 [(2, 3)]
2 [(1, 3)]
3 [(1, 2)]
4 [(5, 6)]
5 [(4, 6)]
6 [(4, 5)]
```